# PHP on an IIS server

Tags: php, iis

I have designed a PHP based website which needs to run on a local server. Unfortunately I have developed this on a [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server using Apache. The machine on which this website will be placed on only supports the IIS server and I am not allowed to install Apache on this this machine.

How do I run PHP code on an IIS server?

Comment: zend and microsoft worked very hard on this issue. It's possible but my suggestion is to use apache with php...

Answer (score 1):

See this link: http://php.iis.net/

99% of stuff is compatible. There can be some problems though (for example if you use mod_rewrite, or some file operation functions behave a little differently).

Answer (score 1):

You can get it installed and include the right infrastructure (IIS, WinCache, and FastCGI, and URL Rewrite) with a single click using Web Platform Installer:

To install PHP 5.2 use:
http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=PHP52

To install PHP 5.3 use:
http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=PHP53

Answer (score 0):

http://php.iis.net/

With IIS 7, a lot of the apache/iis gaps have been closed. Like mod_rewrite is available in IIS 7 (http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got PHP 5.3 running on IIS 6:
http://www.howtoadvice.com/PHPIIS